Name of movie from 6+ years ago
This is a children's movie from at least 6 years ago. 
It starts out with 2 brothers and a sister. The brother is younger (like 10 yo or something) and is bullied because he doesn't like to talk. 
The three kids somehow end up on a planet...I don't remember how. The planet is very dark and organized. There are several rows of houses that lead to a central building. When they get there, the youngest kid asks some person at a desk "whats the protocol" or something  along those lines. I don't remember much after that. 
Towards the end of the movie, the planet is almost alive. The floors and walls break in some places to reveal a blob monster. The child is being manipulated by this monster. The monster tells the child that he isn't understood by others. Eventually his siblings rescue him and they go home.

What was the language? Can you estimate the year and country of production?

Wrinkle in Time? http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0290382/

You might also want to provide a more descriptive question title.

This sounds like the plot of a book "A Wrinkle in time" by Madeleine L'Engle. Great series. This movie/story also three witches/magicians/timeandspacetravelers in it, so if they were in the movie you remember, maybe this is it.

Plot: Meg and Charles Wallace are aided by Calvin and 3 interesting women, Mrs. Which, Mrs Whatsit, and Mrs Who in the search for their father who disappeared during an experiment he was working on for the government.  Their travels take them around the universe to a place unlike any other.

IMDB: A Wrinkle In Time (2003)

Thank you for assisting the community. Please consider adding the following to your answer: a link to the show’s description (like IMDb), an explanation as to why this fits the clues, a storyline or summary of the show, and/or visuals (a clip). I hope you enjoy participating.

This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker. - From Review

@John - the answer did have an IMDB link, I added some detail, made the link more prominent, and addressed some of the other points you brought up, in my edit, though the description has two siblings, not three.
